# How do I make a generic function for addable parameters?

Tags: swift, generics, type-constraints

Working with Swift generics, I have the following question:

This function works as expected with the type Int:

```
func + (number: Int, vector: [Int]) -> [Int] {
    var resArray:[Int]=[]
    for x:Int in vector {
        resArray.append(number+x)
    }
    return resArray
}
```

I want to make it work with any type where addition makes sense.
I have tried the following:

```
func +<T:NSNumber> (number: T.Type, vector: [T.Type]) -> [T.Type] {
    var resArray:[T.Type]=[]
    for x:T.Type in vector {
        resArray.append(number+x)
    }
    return resArray
}
```

But the line:

```
resArray.append(number+x)
```

hits a problem because number and x should obvious support addition.

How should I change my code? I suppose I need to add a constraint on the type. I don't quite know how.

Answer (score 0):

You can define such a constraint as you said, as a protocol like `AdditiveSemigroup` below.

```
protocol AdditiveSemigroup {
    typealias Out = Self
    static func + (a: Self, b: Self) -> Out
}

func +<T: AdditiveSemigroup where T.Out == T> (value: T, vector: [T]) -> [T] {
    return vector.map { $0 + value }
}
```

To make a type conform the protocol above, just define extension on that type.

```
extension String: AdditiveSemigroup {}

"A" + ["A", "B", "C"] // ==> ["AA", "AB", "AC"]
```

For the `NSNumber`, there've been no built-in `+` operatator, so you have to define it by hand.

```
extension NSNumber: AdditiveSemigroup {
    typealias This = NSNumber
}

func + (a: NSNumber, b: NSNumber) -> NSNumber {
    return NSNumber(double: a.doubleValue + b.doubleValue)
}
```

Now you could apply your special `+` operator to values of `NSNumber`.

```
NSNumber(double: 3) + [NSNumber(double: 5)] // ==> 8
```

Comment: I like your idea of a semigroup, but it makes no sense to define an Out typealias, since the definition of a semigroup is for the operation to always return Self. Also the name shoudn't be "Semigroup" since it's specialized to a certain symbol (maybe "AdditiveSemigroup" instead. Also the `where T.Out == T` isn't needed.

Comment: Also `static` isn't needed

Comment: Declaring a method which returns `Self` in a protocol causes that a non-final class (like `NSNumber`) cannot conform to it. And the `where T.Out == T` is just a workaround for that..

Comment: Ahh I see, makes more sense then

Comment: Thank you for the understanding. And  `static` is needed because the built-in `+` operator is not method, if you want a type to conform to the protocol without re-defining any function, like `extension String` does in my answer.